# Example that objects are not all sets in a locally small category

Tags: category-theory, examples-counterexamples

Let $C$ be a locally small category. In this case, is every object set? What would be an example of a locally small category that some objects are not sets?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question correctly, but why doesn't the trivial category with one object (arbitrary proper class) and one morphism (arbitrary set) an example?

Comment: Or if we use the definition of category where objects form a class, then every object of a category is a set, because it is an element of a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least very contrived categories like this. Imagine the disjoint union of the objects with a class like $\bf{Ord}$. The morphisms don't need to be set/class functions so give it the same Hom sets.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're not asking the question you mean to. But to literally answer the question...

In whatever foundations you have in mind, is there anything that is not a set?

If so, let $*$ denote such a thing, and let $S$ be any set. Then, we can define a category where

- the only object is $*$
- the only morphism is $S$

Then this category is locally small (because $\{ S \}$ is a set), and none of its objects are sets.

If not, then the objects of any category must be sets, because everything is a set.

Comment: Exactly. And I actually don't understand the accepted answer.